# PHP Error: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I used a tutorial to create a filterable portfolio from this gist on github > archive-portfolio.php on https://gist.github.com/About2git/1f47cdadce99d886700e

I am seeing an error on my page stating:
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in archive-portfolio.php on line 40.

Line 40 is $count = count($terms); and the full function is:

```
//* Display Picnics Categories
add_action( 'genesis_before_loop', 'sk_isotope_filter' );
function sk_isotope_filter() {

    if ( is_post_type_archive( 'picnics' ) )

        $terms = get_terms( 'picnics_category' );
        $count = count($terms);
        $count = $countarray[0];
        $i=0;
        if ($count > 0) { ?>
            <ul id="picnics-cats" class="filter clearfix">
                <li><a href="#" class="active" data-filter="*"><span><?php _e('All', 'genesis'); ?></span></a></li>
                <?php foreach ($terms as $term ) : ?>
                    <li><a href="#" data-filter=".<?php echo $term->slug; ?>"><span><?php echo $term->name; ?></span></a></li>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul><!-- /picnics-cats -->
        <?php }
}
```

I have tried getting hold of the editor for some time with no response and am hoping someone could assist with the correct code. This error only appeared after a PHP version update.

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you are referring too isn't using a newer version of PHP (v7.3+) and so you could "get away with" not checking if a variable is countable, in more recent versions however this has been fixed and now before you can `count()` a variable you need to first check that it is something you can actually count.

You will need to add a check to see if `$terms` is countable before you can `count` it.

The `is_countable` function was added in to solve this exact problem, [you can read more about it here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-countable.php)

Comment: Thank you for your reply Duenna,

Much appreciated.

I realise that I posted a forked Gist whereas the original is here > https://gist.github.com/srikat/9406477

I tried altering the code with reference to your link with no success.

Unfortunately my PHP is no good. I have messaged the editor again to assist in updating the code. Hopefully he will get back to me.